# How to put colon automatically in text box for mac address with validation (javascript or angularjs)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, textbox, mac-address

I need to put colon (:) automatically after every two digit.
So it will look like: **DD:A4:55:FD:56:CC**

I have write a logic and now I am able to put colon as well, but when I am pressing backspace I am not able to go back from colon.

And it is allowing to write more than two digit when i put cursor on already written two digit, which I don't want.

Here is my code:
  HTML:

```
    <input type="text" ng-model="mac.macAddress" name="macAddress" id="macAddress" 
           maxlength="17" ng-change="macAddressFormat(mac)">
```

JS:

```
$scope.macAddressFormat = function(mac){

        var macAddress  = mac.macAddress;

        var filteredMac = macAddress.replace(/\:/g, '');
        var length  = filteredMac.length;

        if(length % 2 == 0 && length > 1 && length < 12){
            mac.macAddress  = mac.macAddress + ':';
        }
        else{
           console.log('no');
        }
    }
```

Please, know me where I am wrong.
Thanks ! in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify using Regex. I added a default value to your input and added a button which will call this line of code if the length of the macAddress is valid:

```
macAddr.replace(/(.{2})/g,"$1:").slice(0,-1).toUpperCase();
```

The Code:

```js
var app = angular.module("macformat", []); 
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.macAddressFormat = function(mac){

    mac.macAddress = mac.macAddress.toUpperCase();
    var macAddr  = mac.macAddress;
    var alphaNum= /^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/;

    // The Input will be changed only if the length is 12 and is alphanumeric
    if(macAddr.length == 12 && alphaNum.test(macAddr)){
  
        // A lot is going on here. 
        // .replace(/(.{2})/g,"$1:") - adds ':' every other 2 characters
        // .slice(0,-1) - cuts the last character, because ':' is added
        // .toUpperCase() - because it's good practice for writing MAC Addresses
        macAddr = macAddr.replace(/(.{2})/g,"$1:").slice(0,-1).toUpperCase();
    
        // Place Formatted MAC Address to Input
        mac.macAddress = macAddr;
        console.log("Tadaaa");
    }
    // Developer info in console if length is not 12
    else if (macAddr.length < 12 && alphaNum.test(macAddr)){
        console.log(12 - macAddr.length + " characters left");
    }
    else if (macAddr.length > 12 && alphaNum.test(macAddr)){
        console.log(macAddr.length - 12 + " characters too many");
    }
    // Developer info in console if macAddress contains non alpha-numeric
    else if (!alphaNum.test(macAddr)){
        console.log("only alpha-numeric allowed");
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="macformat" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <p>Write MAC Address here without ":" and it will be formatted automatically:</p>
  <input type="text" ng-model="mac.macAddress" name="macAddress" id="macAddress" 
           maxlength="17" ng-change="macAddressFormat(mac)">
  <p><i>Check console for info</i></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answer. But still if u will type dd:jk:ddddddd in text box, then resul will come like DD::JK:DD:DD:DD:DD. So again it will fail !

Isn't there any way to restrict input only for alphanumeric?

Comment: Sure there is. I will add it now.

Comment: Edited. If there are any bugs found, comment.

Comment: Hey, as I am trying to do it on ng-change, it is not working properly. only after first two digit it is making them uppercase and put colon also. after that straight string only. like, DD:jkdddddddd

Comment: Check the code snippet now. I added the code into angular and it works fine. I don't understand where you get stuck.

Comment: Hey, Zirbo.. It's working fine for me.. Thanks a lot for your time and considerations.... :)

Comment: Hey, Zirbo.. Ooopsss ! on backspace still bug... :( please, check after giving backspace type character again.. it won't work

Comment: It says it allows only "alpha-numeric" because this is the formatter not the validator. You could use a validator to check if there is ":" after 2 consecutive letters/digits.

Comment: Add "mac.macAddress = mac.macAddress.toUpperCase();" before  "var macAddr = mac.macAddress;"

Answer (score 0):

Alrighty, so, here is my solution. This filters non-hex, auto-inserts colons, skip over them on delete, allows for insertion, and handles for special cases (like skipping already existing colons). Is it ugly? Yeah, maybe. Does it work? Yeah, in all cases I have found so far. I will update with any missed cases as they arise should I find and fix them. Feel free to use this in your own code, make $$$, and live well.

```
        this.macForm.controls.mac.valueChanges.subscribe((mac: string) => {
            let start = this.searchField.nativeElement.selectionStart;
            let colonStartedAtRight;
            const noColons = mac.replace(/([^A-Za-z0-9])/g, '').toLowerCase();
            const isHex = (parseInt(noColons, 16).toString(16).padStart(noColons.length, ‘0’) === noColons);
            if (!isHex) { start--; }
            if (this.searchMeterForm.controls.searchMeterField.value.charAt(this.searchField.nativeElement.selectionStart) === ':') {
                colonStartedAtRight = true;
            }
            let updatedMac = mac
                .replace(/(^:|[^A-Fa-f0-9:]|:{2,})/g, '') // Restrict characters to only those in MAC addresses
                .toUpperCase();


            for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                updatedMac = updatedMac
                    .replace(/(?:^|:)([A-Fa-f0-9]{1}):/g, '$1') // Auto remove colons around single characters
                    .replace(/([A-Fa-f0-9]{2})([A-Fa-f0-9]{2}|[A-Fa-f0-9]{1})/g, '$1:$2'); // Auto insert colon every 2 characters
            }

            this.searchMeterForm.controls.searchMeterField.patchValue(
                updatedMac.substring(0, 17),
                { emitEvent: false, onlySelf: true }
            );
            const colonBeforeCount = mac.split(':').length - 1;
            const colonAfterCount = this.searchMeterForm.controls.searchMeterField.value.split(':').length - 1;
            const colonAdded = colonAfterCount > colonBeforeCount && start % 3 === 0 ? 1 : 0;
            this.searchField.nativeElement.setSelectionRange(
                start + colonAdded,
                start + colonAdded
            );
            let nowTotalColons = 0;
            for (let i = 0, length = mac.length; i < length; i++) {
                nowTotalColons += mac.charAt(i) === ':' ? 1 : 0;
            }
            if (this.searchMeterForm.controls.searchMeterField.value.charAt(this.searchField.nativeElement.selectionStart) === ':' &&
                !(this.beforeTotalColons > nowTotalColons)) {
                this.searchField.nativeElement.setSelectionRange(
                    this.searchField.nativeElement.selectionStart + 1,
                    this.searchField.nativeElement.selectionStart + 1
                );
            }
            this.beforeTotalColons = nowTotalColons;

            if (this.searchMeterForm.controls.searchMeterField.value.charAt(this.searchField.nativeElement.selectionStart - 1) === ':' &&
                colonStartedAtRight &&
                this.searchField.nativeElement.selectionStart === start) {
                this.searchField.nativeElement.setSelectionRange(
                    this.searchField.nativeElement.selectionStart + 1,
                    this.searchField.nativeElement.selectionStart + 1
                );
            }
        })
```